# How can I change the hard disk serial number in VirtualBox?

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'd like to change the hard disk's serial number in VirtualBox.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: When you say harddisk serial, what do you mean exactly?
Because there are several options...
WMI > Diskdrive > Serial number? or signature? 
or you mean DiskPart > Disk ID?
or you mean Volume serial?

Comment: This is an oldie, but, I think the OP is talking about the ATA serial number.   You change this with `VBoxManage setextradata "yourVM"
      "VBoxInternal/Devices/ahci/0/Config/Port0/SerialNumber" "1234512345"`...

Answer (score 7):

I'm guessing you want to change the UUID of the hard disk
uuid is like this  `UUID {55b773b8-cbcb-42ea-9a44-1368b30ed823}`

To set the UUID of a hard drive run this in command prompt :

`VBoxManage internalcommands setvdiuuid disk2.vdi`

eg: `VBoxManage internalcommands sethduuid disk2.vdi 55b773b8-cbcb-42ea-9a44-1368b30ed823` will work.

Comment: The thing is, drives have a serial number that doesn't correspond to the VBox UUID. In a Linux guest, you can view this with `smartctl -i /dev/whatever`. The serial number shown bears no relation to the UUID.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the command has changed:

```
sethduuid <filepath> [<uuid>]
    Assigns a new UUID to the given image file. This way, multiple copies
    of a container can be registered.
```

So in my case it was:

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage internalcommands sethduuid <vmdk location>
```

`uuid` is changed if you don't fill in a new one either way.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean the Volume Serial Number that you see when you do a dir in de command console.

[VolumeID](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897436.aspx) solved it for me, run it as administrator:

```
volumeid C: C8BA-7B18
```

After the reboot it'd be changed:

```
C:\>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is C8BA-7B18

 Directory of C:\
 ...
```